# Complex Python Regex for Django View

Tags: python, regex, django, url

URL structure look liks this: `<domain>/<version>/<collection>/<sub-collection>/<page>` where domain is anything `a-zA-Z0-9\-\_`, version is anything `a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.` (But would likely be only `1.0`, `1.1`, `2.0.0` etc) and both collection and sub-collection are *optional* groups which follow `<domain>` restraints.

Current regex is: `r'^(?P<domain_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*)\/(?P<version_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*)\/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\/$`.

**How can I capture optional positions, ensuring the last segment is always the page?**

Additionally, is this even a good idea? Would it be better to just pass this through the Django URL conf and let a view function handle all the work?

Example URLs could include:
`administration/5.0.3/reset-user-password`
`user/1.0/getting-started/setting-up-an-account`
`development/3.2/authentication/acl/creating-aco`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*\/)([^\/]*)$` will put the page in $2 and something you'll have to parse in $1.

**OP added:**

The above did the trick. For reference, the full regex became (multi-lined for readability):

`^(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*)/
  (?P<version>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*)/
  (?P<collections>.*)/
  (?P<page>[^\/]*)$`

Comment: This breaks things out the best for me - I just have to handle the collection group in-code, which is reasonable